# 10 year retrospective

Tags: discussion

Hard to imagine that 10 years I was frantically clicking f5 so I could be the first user on the site, but wound up losing out to the bots and being number 4.

Anybody else have any good (or not so good) memories they'd like to relate?

Comment: Thinking we're 10 years since graduation, not 10 years since the beta...  I've really been hanging out here here waaay too long! https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11655/christianity

Comment: Let us savour the joy of the moment!

Answer (score 6):

[image]

**10 year retrospective!**

I have been active for about half that time and have seen how things have changed, both for the good and the bad.

I just would like to do my little part here and **thank** all those who have help make this site what it is.

A special **thanks** goes out to all the former moderators: [David Stratton](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/721/david-stratton), [Caleb](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/users/30/caleb?tab=profile), [Nathaniel](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/users/21576/nathaniel-is-protesting?tab=profile), [El'endia Starman](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/users/58/elendia-starman?tab=profile), [Richard](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/84/richard) and [wax eagle](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/49/wax-eagle?tab=profile). Without their help we would not be where we are today!

> Every valley shall be raised up, every mountain and hill made low; the rough ground shall become level, the rugged places a plain. - [Isaiah 40:4](https://biblehub.com/isaiah/40-4.htm)

My next thought goes out to those who are now God willing enjoying the Lord’s presence in heaven, most notably [Affable Geek](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/1039/affable-geek?tab=profile), who has enjoyed the respect and admiration of many on this site.

> [Requiem æternam](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_Rest) dona ei (eis), Domine. Et lux perpetua luceat ei (eis).

Lastly I would like to thank all who participate on the site making it what it is. We may not always agree with one another, but we are united here for whatever reason and I wish everyone a ***Bon Anniversaire*** to all for these past 10 years.

[image: Bon Anniversaire Gateau]

Comment: And Richard! don't forget good old pro-tem mod [Richard](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/84/richard), I'm not sure we'd have had the balance we've got today without his help

Comment: @PeterTurner Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

Just remembering good old Affable Geek, still the top user on the site.

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/1039/affable-geek

Looking down on us from Heaven, God willing; and making sure that Ken never takes his spot on top.

I loved the way he explained the faith in a fairly generic and vulnerable way that everyone seemed to like.